# what type of collection suits to webservices at .Net?

Tags: .net, web-services, collections

wanna ask for your opinion. What would be the best object (Array, List<>, Collection,...) used in webservice when returning list of business objects. Like a list of customer or history list.

Some ideas:

- because I want minimize amount of data transafered between client and server
- because I want simplify xml serialization
- I dont expect any extra functionality at server side, just simple select

Any tip, opinion most welcome. Cheers, X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use List of the objects you want to return.  You can then specify if you want to to appear as array of T or List at the client (I would use List).

Answer (score 0):

All collections are passed in the same manner.  I pass as `Lists<>` because it is easy to manipulate before serilization.

You can configure the consumer to use whatever you want, and it should be deserialized properly.